# How to add footer to pdf with pdfjam or pdftk?

Tags: pdf, pdftk, pdfjam

I am using a shell script to modify many pdfs and would like to create a script that adds the page number (1 of X format) to the bottom of PDFs in a directory along with the text of the filename.

I tried using pdfjam with this format:

pdfjam --pagenumbering true

but it fails saying undefine pagenumbering

Any other recommendations how to do this? I am OK installing other tools but would like this to all be within a shell script.

Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, what led you to "pagenumbering"?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjam-slides3up

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: `pdfjam --pagecommand '' input.pdf`

By default, pdfjam adds the following LaTeX command to every page: `\thispagestyle{empty}`. By changing the command to an empty command, the default `plain` page style is used, which consists of a page number at the bottom. Of course you may want to play with other styles or layout options to position the page number differently.